# Generalised eigenvectors for Lesliematrix

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If you have a n-th order differential equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^ny}{dx^n}+a_1\frac{d^{n-1}y}{dx^{n-1}} + \dots+a_ny = 0
\end{equation}
You can rewrite it as a system of lineair differential equations
\begin{equation}
u' =Au
\end{equation}
with $A$ a Leslie-matrix. For my class I have to describe the Jordan matrix of A and the matrix $P$ of (generalised) eigenvectors of $A$. I already know how the Jordan matrix looks like, but I don't know how the matrix $P$ wil look like. Can someone please explain this? Much thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generalized eigenvectors of $A$ are elements of the kernel of $(A-\lambda)^n$ where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue and $n$ is the index of the eigenvalue, that is, the size of its largest Jordan block, also the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in the minimal polynomial of $A$. If you already know the Jordan form of $A$ then you know $n$, but in general the easiest way to proceed if you don't know $n$ is to compute the nullspace of $A-\lambda$, then $(A-\lambda)^2$, etc until you have enough generalized eigenvectors to match the algebraic multiplicity of $\lambda$ (that is, the multiplicity of $\lambda$ in the characteristic polynomial).

Once you have all the generalized eigenvectors, they are the columns of $P$ with $P^{-1}AP=JP$ where $J$ is the Jordon matrix for $A$.